# Needing a resource for brain health

Tags: mental-health, brain

I've recently started to do some research about brain health (mentally and physically). I need some concise resources (hopefully a book) to have a general study about brain. Anything from brain hormones to brain ability to learn and its weaknesses (like prejudice!)

> My goal is to gain a better understanding of how we can have a
>   healthy lifestyle or let's say wellbeing.

**Side notes:**

- I do believe that for a youngster with no disabilities, all the wellbeing starts and is controlled by brain!
- I'm a web developer and it's my first question here, please let me know if my question does not fit in this website :)

**Update**: I share some basic understandings and fun facts about brain, so you can figure out what I'm searching for (It's verbose, So you can skip it!):
Recently US companies show a huge interest to corporate wellness programs. It simply means finding a way to get employees involved in physical activities. Setting some incentives like: `If you take at least 7000 steps a day for 10 consecutive days you'd earn 4 hours of PTO (Paid Time Off)`. It seems fine in the first glance, but I believe it's a mitigation, not a solution. It's like pushing a car instead of driving it!
This the point I introduce my own non-technical definition of a healthy brain: ***`A healthy mind is a source of a momentum to what is believed correct, based of brain logical reasoning and experiences.`***
A healthy mind doesn't need any incentive to do what is supposed to be right. If you know seating behind a table and staring to a screen for a long time is not supposed to be a good idea, simply stops doing it. A healthy mind is more a responsible source of decision making, rather than emotional one.
So what about emotions, love, etc. ? If you have played any music instrument, probably you are familiar with music scales. A single music is written in a specific scale. A talented composer selects a note or more out of the default scale. That's the same about life. You should have a normal and healthy lifestyle to fall in love, go for your emotions, etc. And you should know where and how you should select your excepted notes! Otherwise it'd be a chaos (and a healthy mind does not like a chaos) 
In order to recommend a healthy mind we need a better understanding of brain (medically and psychologically). **Phenylethylamine** is a hormone persuading the brain to experience some adventure and even fear. Alcohol makes your brain more emotional. Suppose someone has a crush to another one and either of them are married. Is it a good idea to take alcoholic drinks for a while!
 In a Recently  I heard some news about brain learning capabilities. A normal human brain can learn up to 70 years old brain works like muscles. The more you put rational pressure, the more you learn. If you know all this facts about your brain, you won't waste your time watching stupid TV shows, just because you're 60 years old and you're retired! If you believe how much fun reading a book has, you'd put your time on studying instead.
In a nutshell, having an apprehension of brain, will help me create some meta models of healthy lifestyles, so I can help myself and some other people :)

Comment: Interesting question. Also very trendy concern. Though, could you define what you understand by "brain health (mentally and physically)"? The concept of physically brain health is new (and vague) to me. Thank you. Best regards. M. Arrowsmith

Comment: Sorry for confusion, by physical health I mean non-psychological!

Comment: It's ok, but to be honest, I have still some troubles understanding this concept. But anyway, I was wondering whether a neuroscience book would help you?

Comment: I'm not looking for a super-technical book, any general resource that makes me understand brain and it's general behaviour is fine (or even awesome!)

Comment: This....is incredibly broad.

Answer (score 2):

You state that you are looking for non-psychological health related information, but rather physical health. I understand the distinction you are trying to make to a degree, but am interpreting it as meaning you are not interested in information on how to overcome any sort of psychological abnormality such as mental illness. My below response is based off of this understanding; let me know if I am on the right track!

For general interest in learning in the things you are describing, a good place to start is the psychology or neuroscience section of either your local library or a book store. In these settings you are able to search specific keywords which you are most interested in (ex: wellbeing, neuropsychology, etc) and find books which discuss these topics in a more palatable format than research articles might offer.

Here are some examples of the type of books I am referring to (just examples, the options are limitless!):

"The happiness of pursuit: What neuroscience can teach us about the good life" by Shimon Edelman
Described as: "An informative, accessible, and witty tour of the mind, The Happiness of Pursuit offers insights to a thorough understanding of what minds are, how they relate to each other and to the world, and how we can make the best of it all."

"Mind wide open: Your brain and the neuroscience of everyday life"
By Steven Johnson
Subjects: Neuroscience, neuropsychology, self perception
Summary excerpt: "...Johnson explores how we "read" other people, how the brain processes frightening events (and how we might rid ourselves of the scars those memories leave), what the neurochemistry is behind love and sex, what it means that our brains are teeming with powerful chemicals closely related to recreational drugs, why music moves us to tears, and where our breakthrough ideas come from." 
This one sounds like it might cover many of the interests that you mentioned, might be a good book to start with!

Here is an interesting one that connects physical health and behavior and the possible effects on the brain:
Your brain on food: How chemicals control your thoughts and feelings"
By Gary Lee Wenk
Subject Terms: psychopharmacology, neuropsychology, neurochemistry
Summary: In Your Brain on Food, Dr. Gary Wenk expands his discussion of the effects of specific foods on the brain in a completely updated second edition. From investigations into the benefits and risks of supplements, to the action of gluten in the brain and marijuana's potential for pain relief, Dr. Wenk draws on the latest science to answer a range of fascinating questions such as:
-Is your aluminum cookware hurting you?
-Can tryptophan supplements improve your mood?
-How do fruits and vegetables protect us from aging?
-Why does eating chocolate make you feel so angry?
-Does our brain want us to be obese?

There is a huge range of areas to explore regarding the brain, mind, and body. This is by no means a comprehensive list of the type of books you could explore. I would recommend sampling a number of books and related topics and seeing which ones you are more drawn to. Some of the books you may find are written in a less interesting way and you may decide relatively early that you don't want to finish that book; don't worry, there are tons more out there!

I believe that an understanding of psychology, basic brain functioning and neurotransmitters, and physiology will greatly help in your exploration. That being said, books (or even internet searches) of those areas will also help you understand what you are reading and make connections.